# ansible concatenate to variables one of which is type AnsibleUnsafeText

Tags: ansible

I need to create a partition and subsequently increase a volume group using this new partition in ansible.

I use parted to get the new partition device

then I use `lvg` to extend the volume group. in the `lvg` module I need to pass all the members of the volume group.

```
    ---
- hosts: all
  become: true

  vars:

    disk: sda          # change this
    part_size: 3       # change this
    # next variables are calculated from part_info
    last_number: "{{ part_info.partitions|map(attribute='num')|max }}"
    next_number: "{{ last_number|int + 1 }}"
    rootvg_pvs: "{{ ansible_lvm.pvs | dict2items | selectattr('value.vg', 'match', 'rootvg') | map(attribute='key') | list  }}"
    new_pvs: "/dev/{{ disk }}{{ next_number }}"

  tasks:
    - name: get disk info
      parted:
        device: "/dev/{{ disk }}"
        unit: "{{ unit }}"
      register: part_info
    - debug:
        msg:|-
          current_pvs: {{ rootvg_pvs | union(new_pvs) }}
```

`rootvg_pvs` is a list containing all the current member of the volume group `'rootvg'`

`new_pvs` is the new disk eg dev/sdaX

for some strange reason the `new_pvs` variable is of type `AnsibleUnsafeText` and I am not able to add this to the rootvg_pvs list

my questions: why is new_pvs of type `AnsibleUnsafeText`?

How can I concatenate the two variables in a single list so that I can extend the volume group using the `lvg` ansible module.
Note my version of ansible does not have the `pvresize` option. so I need to pass a list of all member of the volume groups to extend to the `lvg` module

I have errors similar to this:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on (current_pvs: {{ rootvg_pvs  | union(new_pvs) }}): can only concatenate list (not \"AnsibleUnsafeText\") to list"}
```

Comment: As the error messages says it you cannot concatenate lists and another type, whatever it is (do not focus too much on the `AnsibleUnsafeText`). So to make it work put your new element in a list: `[new_pvs]` => `{{ rootvg_pvs + [new_pvs] }}`